# SAS or Python Extracting Map for Directions as Picture

Tags: python, google-maps, sas

I would like to use SAS or Python to achieve this.

I have multiple points that I would like to map out using mapquest/maps.google/maps.bing, and then download a screenshot of the map on to my C: drive.

This would not be a one time thing. I would need it to download multiple maps (Have a map for route within Chicago, then another for a route within Pittsburgh).

I was hoping there may be a module within Python that enables this.

Also, on a side note, is there a way to call Python scripts from within a SAS program? Could I possibly embed it in to a VBA script which is then called from SAS?

Answer (score 1):

[The family of Google Maps APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html) lets you call down various services from any language that will let you send a URL request.  The Static API might be of special interest to you, though I'm not sure if you can overlay directions, or how.

To do this in Python, you could use `urllib` for interacting with the API; there's also [pymaps](http://code.google.com/p/pymaps/).

Answer (score 1):

You *should* be able to do the lot from SAS if the APIs for Google/MapQuest/Bing all support URI requests...

In SAS you can make the API request and retrieve and process the data.  An example is shown [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140830105300/http://www.runsubmit.com/questions/402/using-sas-to-pull-rss-data).

I'm not sure what the API request is going to return or how you would then use/interpret that.  If it's standard XML use the SAS XML mapper.  If it's anything else (ie. Image/MIME data) then things may get trickier.

Comment: I'll have to look in to the XML mapper, but so far we have it pulling a html file that has the map, but it's embedded with javascript. I just want a .png or .jpeg of the route.